# AWS Cognito getSession in Swift resulting in 401 unauthorized from API GW

Tags: swift, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

When our app launches, we check if we have valid AWS Cognito tokens (id, refresh, access). If they are not valid anymore, we fetch these manually by using the cognito IDP getSession method.

Because it takes a bit of time to fetch these tokens, our app continues ahead to make API calls and gets a 401 unauthorized response from API Gateway. We are performing these actions while showing the loading indicator to the user.

Is there a way for us to ensure that we have received a valid token before making an API call? Our hack right now is that we retry if we get a 401 unauthorized response. This is not efficient as we waste one (sometimes more) API call(s) while the tokens are refreshing.

I have looked into using DispatchGroups (GCD) and DispatchQueue but that hasn't helped us. Looking for suggestions as to how we can improve this further. Below is the code we are using to refresh tokens:

```
func getTokens(){
        self.user?.getSession().continueOnSuccessWith { (task) -> AnyObject? in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                let idTok = task.result?.idToken?.tokenString ?? "ERR"
                    ... handle received tokens ...
            })
            return nil
        }
    }
```

Side note: We are importing the "AWSCognitoIdentityProvider" into our app and my understanding was that it should automatically be renewing tokens but I am not seeing this behavior. However, when we run the getTokens() function, it will sometime get the newest tokens from Cognito and at other times, it will provide the cached results.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by triggering my next function inside the AWSTask. Not ideal but works.